# Botão Aumentar, Diminuir e Impressão

Tags: javascript, html

Estou usando o bootstrap e por padrão a fonte é 1rem quando clico no botão imprimir ele não pega o tamanho padrão do documento ele pega uma fonte bem pequena,  para montar o botão de aumentar e diminuir fonte estou usando um jquery **Jfontsize** será que tem algo que atrapalhe ele pegar o tamanho de fonte certo.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

```
     $('a, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, img, figcaption, footer, span, li, ul, ol, td, th, tr').jfontsize({
        btnMinusClasseId: '#jfontsize-m2', 
        btnDefaultClasseId: '#jfontsize-d2', 
        btnPlusClasseId: '#jfontsize-p2', 
        btnMinusMaxHits: 1,
        btnPlusMaxHits: 3, 
        sizeChange: 5
    });
```

**jquery.jfontsize-2.js**

```
(function($) {
  return $.fn.jfontsize = function(opcoes) {
    var $this, apply, current_size, defaults, save;
    $this = $(this);
    defaults = {
      btnMinusClasseId: "#jfontsize-minus",
      btnDefaultClasseId: "#jfontsize-default",
      btnPlusClasseId: "#jfontsize-plus",
      btnMinusMaxHits: 10,
      btnPlusMaxHits: 10,
      sizeChange: 1
    };
    if (opcoes) {
      opcoes = $.extend(defaults, opcoes);
    }
    save = function() {
      return $.jStorage.set("jfontsize", current_size);
    };
    apply = function() {
      return $this.each(function(i) {
        var fontsize, size;
        if (!($(this).data("initial_size") != null)) {
          fontsize = $(this).css("font-size");
          fontsize = parseInt(fontsize.replace("px", ""));
          $(this).data("initial_size", fontsize);
        }
        size = $(this).data("initial_size") + (current_size * opcoes.sizeChange);
        return $(this).css("font-size", size + "px");
      });
    };
    $(opcoes.btnMinusClasseId + ", " + opcoes.btnDefaultClasseId + ", " + opcoes.btnPlusClasseId).removeAttr("href");
    $(opcoes.btnMinusClasseId + ", " + opcoes.btnDefaultClasseId + ", " + opcoes.btnPlusClasseId).css("cursor", "pointer");
    current_size = $.jStorage.get("jfontsize", 0);
    if (current_size === (-opcoes.btnMinusMaxHits)) {
      $(opcoes.btnMinusClasseId).addClass("btn-secondary disabled");
    }
    if (current_size === opcoes.btnPlusMaxHits) {
      $(opcoes.btnPlusClasseId).addClass("btn-secondary disabled");
    }
    apply();
    $(opcoes.btnMinusClasseId).click(function() {
      $(opcoes.btnPlusClasseId).removeClass("btn-secondary disabled");
      if (current_size > (-opcoes.btnMinusMaxHits)) {
        current_size--;
        if (current_size === (-opcoes.btnMinusMaxHits)) {
          $(opcoes.btnMinusClasseId).addClass("btn-secondary disabled");
        }
        apply();
        return save();
      }
    });
    $(opcoes.btnDefaultClasseId).click(function() {
      $(opcoes.btnMinusClasseId).removeClass("btn-secondary disabled");
      $(opcoes.btnPlusClasseId).removeClass("btn-secondary disabled");
      current_size = 16;
      $this.each(function(i) {
        return $(this).css("font-size", $(this).data("initial_size") + "px");
      });
      return save();
    });
    return $(opcoes.btnPlusClasseId).click(function() {
      $(opcoes.btnMinusClasseId).removeClass("btn-secondary disabled");
      if (current_size < opcoes.btnPlusMaxHits) {
        current_size++;
        if (current_size === opcoes.btnPlusMaxHits) {
          $(opcoes.btnPlusClasseId).addClass("btn-secondary disabled");
        }
        apply();
        return save();
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Não sei se vai resolver, mas vai lá no final do seu CSS e coloca um `@media only print { body { font-size:1rem !important;} }` e testa no preview de impressão pra ver se resolve ai.

Comment: ele ainda deixa a fonte pequena :/

Comment: Vc quer diminuir ou aumentar na impressão? Se for para diminuir tem que ser `@media only print { body { font-size:0.5rem !important;} }` por exemplo...

Comment: na verdade o aumentar e diminuir funciona o que está dando problema é que quando eu clico no botão para voltar a fonte ao normal e clico em imprimir a fonte fica pequena, eu não quero travar na hora de imprimir um tamanho de fonte, quero que se o usuário aumentar a fonte ele consiga imprimir grande